# Keyup handler is not getting called for my input element

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

I am new to javascript, so this may seem like a trivial question. I am trying trying to write a javascript program that will insert dashes into a phone number, but I can't get my code to work. Nothing is happening when I use `onkeyup`.

Am I doing something wrong? So far, it seems like only `onfocus` is working for me.

```js
function keyup() {
  var mystring;
  mystring.concat(document.getElementById('Phone').value, '-');
  document.getElementById('Phone').setAttribute('value', mystring);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Phone" name="Phone" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="###-###-####" onkeyup="keyup">
```

My editor has issues and is highlighting stuff. Is there an issue with single quotes double quotes? Are the returns in the lines alright? It appears ok when I view the source on Chrome version 66.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said in your question, this is what you want:

```js
function keyup() {
  var mystring = document.getElementById('Phone').value;
  document.getElementById('Phone').value = mystring + "-";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Phone" name="Phone" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="###-###-####" oninput="keyup()" />
```

- you need to put `()` after the `keyup` in `onkeyup="keyup"`
- you were `concat`ing to `undefined`
- you don't need to even use `concat`, just use the `+` operator
- replace `setAttribute("value", ...)` with `.value = ...`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929797/setattribute-doesnt-work-the-way-i-expect-it-to) for more info
- use the `input` event instead of `keyup`. Otherwise, a `-` will be added for every key press

Notice that this will put a `-` after *every* number. If you want something different, which you presumably do, clarify what you want in your question.

Comment: This finally gets a hyphen going thankyou so now I should be able to used conditionals on the length of the string?

Comment: Yes, you can use `if` statements to determine when to add hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parenthesis on 'onkeyup' attribute.

Plus you have to declare a string value to variable 'mystring' before calling the 'concat' method from it.

Something like:

```
<script>
  function keyup() {
  console.log("keyup!!")
    var mystring = "";
    mystring.concat(document.getElementById('Phone').value, '-');
    document.getElementById('Phone').setAttribute('value', mystring);
  }
</script>

<input type="text" id="Phone" name="Phone" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="###-###-####" onkeyup="keyup()">
```

Comment: I tried using this code and nothing still happens ..do i need the script above the input? i currently have at the bottom of the body.  where can I see console log?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function keyup() {
  var mystring = document.getElementById('Phone').value + '-'

  document.getElementById('Phone').value=mystring;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Phone" name="Phone" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="###-###-####" onkeyup="keyup()">
```