# input box never clears - but works fine on codepen

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple input form.

```
<div id="inputboxforemailandpassword">
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
</div>    
<hr>       
<div id="apistatusmessage">
  <p>loading...</p>
</div>        
<button id = "buttonregister" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="registration()" >
  register
</button>     
<button id = "clearinput" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="clearouttheinputboxes()" >
  clearinput
</button>
```

and this is the clear function i am using.

```
function clearouttheinputboxes()
{
    var logopener="----entering clearouttheinputboxes----";
    console.log(logopener);    

    //collect the email address and password.
    var emailaddress = document.getElementById("inputEmail");
    var password = document.getElementById("inputPassword");

    emailaddress.setAttribute('value', "");
    password.setAttribute('value', "");

    var logcloser="----leaving clearouttheinputboxes----";
    console.log(logcloser);    
}
```

I have replicated this on my codepen, here.

https://codepen.io/jay-pancodu/pen/oNbVrVV

The issue is this.

a) on codepen, the exact same code, clears the input box just fine.
b) on my web app, the input boxes remain, no matter how many times i try to clear and whichever value I use in the value.

So, what am I doing wrong here.

**Update 1 - Lot of comments suggesting I use something like this**

```
password.value = "some value";
```

that does not solve the problem for me. please check that I am getting the output in codepen. dont want to use .value method.

**Update 2 - It looks like CodePen code does not work either**

**Update 3 - Recreating the issue on CodePen**

able to set and clear input boxes before anything is typed. but once you type in the boxes, the ability to set and clear values is lost

Comment: For me it is not working on the codepen also :(.
Instead of setting attribute like  emailaddress.setAttribute('value', ""); do emailaddress.value = '';

Comment: It doesn't work for me either.

Comment: that does not work either. already tried. besides, is it not better to use setAttribute as much as possible?

Comment: @GirkovArpa what do you mean? you have same issue in your app is what you are trying to say?

Comment: The codepen does not work for me.  I click the clear button and nothing happens.  Even after writing something in the boxes.

Comment: @GirkovArpa I just realized, you are right. So, yeah, the issue is present in both codepen and my code. thanks for testing that for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29929977/4712626
@Jay Check this out it answers your exact question.

Comment: @TauseefAhmad you are right!!!! oh wow, that means, the below answer is correct. thanks man.

Comment: I do not see a `FORM`

Comment: it was just/only a input box group without an actual form/submit combo. just collecting input but not submitting it. @ProfessorAbronsius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the `.setAttribute('value', "")` method with the below mentioned approach should work

```
function clearouttheinputboxes()
    {
        var logopener="----entering clearouttheinputboxes----";
        console.log(logopener);    
    
        //collect the email address and password.
    
        var emailaddress = document.getElementById("inputEmail");
        var password = document.getElementById("inputPassword");
    
        // emailaddress.setAttribute('value', "");
        // password.setAttribute('value', "");

        //replace the above 2 lines with the below code
    
        emailaddress.value = "";
        password.value = "";
    
        var logcloser="----leaving clearouttheinputboxes----";
        console.log(logcloser);    
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my question. dont wish to use .value.

Comment: Ok. Also, do check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929797/setattribute-doesnt-work-the-way-i-expect-it-to which explains when and why the .setAttribute() method is used. Might help

Answer (score 1):

Try this `element.value=""`

```js
function clearouttheinputboxes()
{
    var logopener="----entering clearouttheinputboxes----";
    console.log(logopener);    

    //collect the email address and password.
    var emailaddress = document.getElementById("inputEmail");
    var password = document.getElementById("inputPassword");

    emailaddress.value=""
    password.value=""

    var logcloser="----leaving clearouttheinputboxes----";
    console.log(logcloser);    
}
```

```html
<div id="inputboxforemailandpassword">
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
</div>    
<hr>       
<div id="apistatusmessage">
  <p>loading...</p>
</div>        
<button id = "buttonregister" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="registration()" >
  register
</button>     
<button id = "clearinput" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="clearouttheinputboxes()" >
  clearinput
</button>
```

Comment: I have updated my question. dont wish to use .value.

Comment: eventually, i had to use .value

Answer (score 1):

I think you perhaps over-complicated the issue and used too many functions for seemingly quite a simple task. The goal is, I believe, to `clear` or `set` ( some predetermined value ) in the form inputs unless the user has actually entered some data themselves? To that end perhaps the following might be of interest - a single function handles both buttons `clear` and `set` ( was unsure that the third button was for )

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{

    let div=document.getElementById('inputboxforemailandpassword');
    let col=div.querySelectorAll('input[name="email"],input[name="password"]');
    
    let clickhandler=function(e){
        col.forEach( input=>{
            switch( this.textContent.toLowerCase() ){
                case 'clear':
                    if( input.value=='' || input.value==input.dataset.example )input.value='';
                break;
                case 'set':
                    if( input.value=='' && input.value!=input.dataset.example )input.value=input.dataset.example;
                break;
            }
        })
    };
    
    div.querySelectorAll('button').forEach( bttn=>{
        bttn.addEventListener( 'click', clickhandler );
    });
});
```

```css
label{display:block;width:100%;margin:0.25rem auto;}
label input{float:right}
fieldset{border:1px dotted gray;margin:0.5rem auto}
```

```html
<div id='inputboxforemailandpassword'>
    <fieldset>
        <label class='sr-only'>
            Email address 
            <input type='email' name='email' class='form-control' placeholder='Email address' data-example='joe.bloggs@example.com' autocomplete='off' autofocus='true' required />
        </label>
        
        <label class='sr-only'>
            Password
            <input type='password' name='password' class='form-control' placeholder='Password' data-example='P45$W0rd' autocomplete='off' required />
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'>clear</button>    
      <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'>set</button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: I now realized that I misunderstood the usage of setAttribute. I realized after posting this question, that the function clearly states,setAttribute, and I was using that to set a value. that was my major issue and using the value option solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly change the value of any input field = '' (blank)

I am updating your code a little bit. what I am doing, is directly changing the value of input fields.

```
function clearouttheinputboxes() {
   var logopener="----entering clearouttheinputboxes----";
   console.log(logopener);    

  //----directly changing values of the input fields by "id"
  document.getElementById("inputEmail").value = '';
  document.getElementById("inputPassword").value = '';


  var logcloser="----leaving clearouttheinputboxes----";
  console.log(logcloser);
```

}

if you face issues, please comment or reply, so that I can understand the issue better.